# POSTFIX: Sender address rejected: Domain not found (in reply to MAIL FROM command)

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix, address

My mail server not recognize $mydestination, why?

```
sproxy:/var/spool/mail # tail -f /var/log/mail | grep vinicius.lehmann
Oct  6 11:13:21 sproxy amavis[31008]: (31008-17) Passed CLEAN {RelayedInternal}, MYNETS LOCAL [192.168.0.125]:57464 [192.168.0.125] <Aberturati@sales.intra> -> <vinicius.lehmann@salessupermercados.com.br>, Queue-ID: D9C3F29BA4, Message-ID: <5613D6FD.6050200@sales.intra>, mail_id: 9fhyBbjNt7nl, Hits: -2.899, size: 638, queued_as: 13D0E29BC8, 2604 ms
Oct  6 11:13:21 sproxy postfix/smtp[31091]: D9C3F29BA4: to=<vinicius.lehmann@salessupermercados.com.br>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=2.7, delays=0.04/0/0/2.6, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 13D0E29BC8)
Oct  6 11:13:23 sproxy postfix/smtp[31032]: 13D0E29BC8: to=<vinicius.lehmann@salessupermercados.com.br>, relay=smtp.terra.com.br[208.84.244.140]:25, delay=1.5, delays=0.45/0/0.91/0.15, dsn=4.1.8, status=deferred (host smtp.terra.com.br[208.84.244.140] said: 450 4.1.8 <Aberturati@sales.intra>: Sender address rejected: Domain not found (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
```

But few address are sending and receiving

```
sproxy:/var/spool/mail # tail -f /var/log/mail | grep alvaro
Oct  6 11:16:01 sproxy amavis[31674]: (31674-15) Passed CLEAN {RelayedInternal}, MYNETS LOCAL [192.168.0.125]:57498 [192.168.0.125] <Aberturati@sales.intra> -> <alvarocassini@sproxy.sales.intra>, Queue-ID: 2697B29BC2, Message-ID: <5613D79C.8070303@sales.intra>, mail_id: nee-tFeqs5fk, Hits: -2.9, size: 625, queued_as: A7B9B29BCA, 2785 ms
Oct  6 11:16:01 sproxy postfix/smtp[31866]: 2697B29BC2: to=<alvarocassini@sproxy.sales.intra>, orig_to=<alvaro@salessupermercados.com.br>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=4.1, delays=1.2/0.11/0/2.8, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as A7B9B29BCA)
Oct  6 11:16:01 sproxy postfix/local[31356]: A7B9B29BCA: to=<alvarocassini@sproxy.sales.intra>, relay=local, delay=1.6, delays=1.6/0/0/0.04, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Oct  6 11:16:06 sproxy popper[32156]: Stats: alvarocassini 0 0 167 5730100 187.85.83.226 187.85.83.226 [pop_updt.c:301]
Oct  6 11:17:00 sproxy popper[32255]: Stats: alvarocassini 0 0 167 5730112 187.85.83.226 187.85.83.226 [pop_updt.c:301]
Oct  6 11:17:22 sproxy popper[32306]: Stats: alvarocassini 0 0 167 5730112 187.85.83.226 187.85.83.226 [pop_updt.c:301]

sproxy:/var/spool/mail # dig salessupermercados.com.br

; <<>> DiG 9.8.4-P2 <<>> salessupermercados.com.br
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 62144
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;salessupermercados.com.br.     IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
salessupermercados.com.br. 57934 IN     A       216.70.89.60

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
salessupermercados.com.br. 57934 IN     NS      ns3.terraempresas.com.br.
salessupermercados.com.br. 57934 IN     NS      ns2.terraempresas.com.br.

;; Query time: 7 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Oct  6 11:26:59 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 109

sproxy:/var/spool/mail # dig salessupermercados.com.br MX

; <<>> DiG 9.8.4-P2 <<>> salessupermercados.com.br MX
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 35366
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;salessupermercados.com.br.     IN      MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
salessupermercados.com.br. 57927 IN     MX      5 mx.terraempresas.com.br.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
salessupermercados.com.br. 57927 IN     NS      ns2.terraempresas.com.br.
salessupermercados.com.br. 57927 IN     NS      ns3.terraempresas.com.br.

;; Query time: 67 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Oct  6 11:27:06 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 112
```

Configuration postfix/main.cf

```
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
myhostname = sproxy.sales.intra
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
biff = no

delay_warning_time = 1h
disable_dns_lookups = no
disable_mime_output_conversion = no
masquerade_classes = envelope_sender, header_sender, header_recipient
masquerade_domains = sales.intra
#masquerade_domains = salessupermercados.com.br
masquerade_exceptions = root
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, salesssupermercados.com.br, sales.intra
mynetworks_style = subnet
relayhost = smtp.terra.com.br

alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/canonical
relocated_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relocated
sender_canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_canonical
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
mail_spool_directory = /var/mail
message_strip_characters = \0
defer_transports =
mailbox_command =
mailbox_transport =
mailbox_size_limit = 0
#message_size_limit = 10240000
message_size_limit = 51200000
strict_8bitmime = no
strict_rfc821_envelopes = no

smtpd_helo_required = no
smtpd_helo_restrictions =

smtpd_client_restrictions =

smtpd_sender_restrictions = hash:/etc/postfix/access

smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination


############################################################
# SASL stuff
############################################################
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
############################################################
# TLS stuff
############################################################
#tls_append_default_CA = no
relay_clientcerts =
#tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom

smtp_use_tls = no
#smtp_tls_loglevel = 0
smtp_enforce_tls = no
smtp_tls_CAfile =
smtp_tls_CApath =
smtp_tls_cert_file =
smtp_tls_key_file =
#smtp_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtp_tls_session_cache_database =

smtpd_use_tls = no
#smtpd_tls_loglevel = 0
smtpd_tls_CAfile =
smtpd_tls_CApath =
smtpd_tls_cert_file =
smtpd_tls_key_file =
smtpd_tls_ask_ccert = no
smtpd_tls_received_header = no
```

Answer (score 4):

The error message you got back from the remote mail server was:

> host smtp.terra.com.br[208.84.244.140] said: 450 4.1.8 : Sender address rejected: Domain not found (in reply to MAIL FROM command)

This means that the *FROM* address was rejected by them because a DNS lookup on that domain failed.

The domain in question is `sales.intra` which doesn't seem to be resolving on any DNS server I can find.

To make this work you will either need to make `sales.intra` resolve in public DNS or change the FROM address to something that does resolve.

The email that worked was delivered locally rather than to a remote server.  Your local server does not check the FROM address for a valid, working domain so it continued processing the email.

Comment: But how it is configured in the variable $mydestination the salessupermercados.com.br domain, the local server should not accept email him rather than sending to the external server ?